# Strange behavior of Timer class in Android

Tags: android, view, timer

Hi I am using Timer class in order to obtain feature if user presses **Left** or **Right** arrow key on keyboard(keyboard is attached to android device) it will display a View(make it **VISIBLE**) on the screen. If there is no input(left or right arrow press) in next 5 sec the view will gone.

**The code** that I am using to make **View** to become **GONE**:

```
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {
            Log.i(PLAYER_ACTIVITY_TAG, "Left/right pressed ");
            meciaControlTimer.cancel();
            if (keyTimer == null) {
                keyTimer = new Timer();
                keyTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(new HideEvent());
                        Log.i(PLAYER_ACTIVITY_TAG, "Hide fired - Left/Right key was not pressed in past 5 sec");
                    }
                }, 5000);
            } else {
                Log.i(PLAYER_ACTIVITY_TAG, "Canceling the key timer!");
                keyTimer.cancel();
                keyTimer = null;
            }
        }
```

**The problem:**
I have observed that if I make 15-20 key inputs(left/right arrow) in short period of time(a few secs) the **EventBus**(I am using this class instead of Broadcasts in android) will never be triggered and the View remains VISIBLE until I make new input and wait a little bit(1-2 sec) between another input.

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong or to explain me what is going on with this Timer and why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is if you are seeing the log in else then the issue reproduces.

Comment: Actually, when this issue occurs Log in else section was never executed.